# Laravel: Failed to send variable (Undefined Variable)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at Laravel. and i got a little problem with view.

here is my controller

```
public function main_menu()
{   
    $mainmenus = DB::table('main_menus')->get();

    $subs = $mainmenus;
    foreach ($subs as $key => $value) 
    {
        $subs[$key] = DB::table('sub_menus')
                        ->where('parent_id', '=' , $value->main_id)
                        ->get();
    }

    $products = DB::table('sub_menus')->get();
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        $products[$key] = DB::table('products')
                                -> where('product_parent', '=', $value->sub_id)
                                ->get();
    }

    $data = array("mainmenus" => $mainmenus,
            "submenus" => $subs,
            "productmenus" => $products);

    return View::make('layouts/nav', $data);

}
```

and here is my layouts/nav.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts_index')

 @section('nav')
 <div class="nav">
 <nav class="navbar">
    <ul id="menu">

        <li class="active"><a href="index" class="drop"><i class="icon-home icon-small">  </i>Home</a></li>

        @foreach ($mainmenus as $key=>$mainmenu) 
            <li>
                <a href="menu/{{ $mainmenu->main_id }}" class="drop">
                <i class="icon-{{ $mainmenu->main_icon }} icon-small"></i>{{ $mainmenu->main_title_id }}</a>
                @if( $mainmenu->main_desc_id != "")
                    <div class="dropdown_3columns">
                        <div class="col_4">
                            <h3><i class="icon-{{ $mainmenu->main_icon }} icon-large"></i>{{ $mainmenu->main_title_id }}</h3>
                            <h4>{{ $mainmenu->main_desc_id }}</h4>  
                        </div>
                        @foreach ($submenus[$key] as $key=>$submenu) 
                            <div class="col_1">
                                <a href="" ><h5><i class="icon-small icon-bookmark"></i>{{ $submenu->sub_title_id }}</h5></a>   

                                <ul>
                                @foreach ($productmenus[$key] as $productmenu)
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="" ><i class="icon-small icon-th-large"></i>{{ $productmenu->product_title_id }}</a>
                                    </li>   
                                @endforeach

                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        @endforeach

                    </div>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
        <li class="last"><a href="#" class="drop "><i class="icon-pencil icon-small"></i>Tentang Kami</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
 </div>

@stop
```

my routes:

```
  Route::get('/', 'ShowsController@index');
```

when i try to run the index.blade.php it says:
Undefined variable: mainmenus (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mestika\app\views\layouts\nav.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mestika\app\views\layouts\nav.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mestika\app\views\layouts\nav.blade.php)

what i want to do is i want to show main_menu at every view pages. i've tried changed view::make to view::share. but no luck. is there anything i miss at here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `view composer` for the menu/nav, so you don't have to build the navigation in every view manually, for example, put this code in a file named `nav.php` and put the file inside `app/start` folder then include it from `app/start/global.php` file:

```
// app/start/nav.php
View::composer('layouts_index', function($view){

    // Prepare the menuitems here

    $mainmenus = DB::table('main_menus')->get();
    $subs = 'Prepare it here...';
    $productmenus = 'Prepare it'

    return $view->with('mainmenus', $mainmenus)
                ->with('submenus', $submenus)
                ->with('products', $products);

});
```

In your `app/start/global.php` file (at the bottom) add this:

```
require 'nav.php';
```

Now, every time you extend the `layouts_index.blade.php` your menu items ($mainmenus, $submenus, $productmenus) will be available in the main layout. So, you may use something like this in the layout:

```
@if(isset($mainmenus))
    @foreach ($mainmenus as $key => $mainmenu)
        {{ 'Use it here...' }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Now, in your `Controller`, when you are passing any data to any view that extends `layouts_index` you don't need to pass the menu items manually, because those will be passed by `Framework` by `view composer` you have created.

If you don't want to pass the menu items for `products` then just remove the `->with('products', $products)` from your view composer, so only `$mainmenus and $submenus` will be passed automatically to the main layout and you can pass the `$products` manually from any controller. Check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout#.VDNaxfmSySo).

Comment: i tried your suggestions. but i got a blank when refresh it.

Comment: Make sure you are extending the right layout, view composer is bound to the `layouts_index`, is this right master layout?

Comment: oh i forgot <?php at my app/nav.php. when i included it repeating my index not my navigation. like looping forever i think.

Comment: alright i got the problem. at my layout_blade i use include instead of yield. i changed it and now it can load. but the nav not shown.

Comment: it solved. actually at nav.php i can't view:composer other view file. (nav.blade.php) so i tried to move the nav.blade.php to layouts.blade.php. and it works like charm.